# How to Show/Hide divs with the same class name individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to implement answers I found on stackoverflow asked by other people, but I'm not getting the results that I want.

I have an about section on a site I'm building. In that section I have four different about items. At the bottom is a button and when that button is clicked I want the four boxes to be hidden and for a large about item to appear(show) in their place and display the information of the about item who's button was clicked. With the code I have now, when I click one of the buttons, all large about item divs show up instead of just one. Is it possible to just display only one large about item(showfullabout) when clicked, instead of all four? I want to individually show items when clicked.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 showfullabout">
    <div class="about-item-full">
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <h2>Description</h2>
         <p>Content</p>
        <button class="small-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6- col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="about-item">
        <div class="about-item-top">
            <img src="img/img07.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="about-item-circle">
                <span class="oi oi-justify-left"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-item-bottom">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>
                Content
            </p>
            <button class="full-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END ITEM-->
</div>
<!--END COLUMN-->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 showfullabout">
    <div class="about-item-full">
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <h2>Description</h2>
         <p>Content</p>
        <button class="small-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6- col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="about-item">
        <div class="about-item-top">
            <img src="img/img07.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="about-item-circle">
                <span class="oi oi-image"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-item-bottom">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>
                Content
            </p>
            <button class="full-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END ITEM-->
</div>
<!--END COLUMN-->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 showfullabout">
    <div class="about-item-full">
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <h2>Description</h2>
         <p>Content</p>
        <button class="small-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6- col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="about-item">
        <div class="about-item-top">
            <img src="img/img07.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="about-item-circle">
                <span class="oi oi-monitor"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-item-bottom">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>
                Content
            </p>
            <button class="full-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END ITEM-->
</div>
<!--END COLUMN-->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 showfullabout">
    <div class="about-item-full">
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <h2>Description</h2>
         <p>Content</p>
         <button class="small-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6- col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="about-item">
        <div class="about-item-top">
            <img src="img/img07.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="about-item-circle">
                <span class="oi oi-location"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-item-bottom">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>
                Content
            </p>
            <button class="full-about"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END ITEM-->
</div>
<!--END COLUMN-->

<!--CSS-->
.showfullabout{
display:none;
}

<!--Script-->
$("button.full-about").click(function(){
    $(".about-item").hide();
    $(".showfullabout").fadeToggle(500);
});
$("button.small-about").click(function(){
    $(".about-item").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".showfullabout").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relative selectors to find the target elements

```
$("button.full-about").click(function () {
    $(".about-item").hide();
    $(this).closest(".about-item").parent().prev('.showfullabout').fadeIn(500);
});
$("button.small-about").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".showfullabout").hide();
    $(".about-item").fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0bz5Lou2/)

In the case of button `full-about` you need to hide all `about-item` elements and show the previous sibling of the ancestor `about-item`'s parent, the opposite for `small-about` button

Comment: With your fix, I am able to get only an individual large about item(showfullabout) instead of all four. Which is the result I want, but the small about item that was clicked on is hidden, while the other three are displayed underneath. Is there a way to make all small about items hide or be hidden when only one is clicked, while still only displaying one large about item(showfullabout)? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @irunintotrees sorry missed a `.` in `.showfullabout` in the first handler

Comment: @irunintotrees also can you repeat the requirement about required display status

Comment: Thank You Arun P Johny. I caught the missed . in .showfullabout. Also the demonstration from the JSFiddle link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.